# Python easygui not displaying, based on boolean value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to display an `easygui` message box, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why it isn't displaying.  I think that my `std` is a DataFrame which is why I went with using the `any()` function.

But when I run this script, the message box does not display.  Any suggestions on how to get this running will be appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import easygui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data_test6.txt", sep="\[|\]\[|\]",engine = 'python', header = None)
    data = data.iloc[0, ::4]
    data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1]).astype(float)
    data.pop(0)
    xar = range(len(data))
    yar = pd.DataFrame(data)
    yar = yar[1050:len(data)]
    xar = xar[1050:len(data)]
    #std = pd.rolling_std(yar,1000).plot(style='b')
    std = yar.rolling(window=1000).std() 
    mean = yar.rolling(window=1000).mean()

    if any(std>0.0006):
          easygui.msgbox('Alert!', 'Dialog Box 1')


    ax1.clear()
    ax1.set_xlabel("Test")
    ax2.clear()
    ax3.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,std)
    ax2.plot(xar,mean)
    ax3.plot(xar,yar)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=.01)
plt.show()
```

My data is streaming into the text file as follows:

```
[0.0263671875, 0.0400390625, 1.0048828125][0.017578125, 0.029296875, 0.8486328125][0.017578125, 0.029296875, 0.8486328125][0.017578125, 0.029296875, 0.8486328125][0.017578125, 0.029296875, 0.8486328125][0.017578125, 0.029296875, 0.8486328125][0.017578125, 0.029296875, 0.8486328125][0.017578125, 0.029296875, 0.8486328125][0.0224609375, 0.037109375, 1.046875][0.0224609375, 0.037109375, 1.046875][0.0224609375, 0.037109375, 1.046875][0.0224609375, 0.037109375, 1.046875][0.0224609375, 0.037109375, 1.046875][0.0224609375, 0.037109375, 1.046875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0029296875][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0068359375][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.0361328125, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0361328125, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.0341796875, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0078125][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.0224609375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.021484375, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625]
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with easygui. The problem lies with your if statement, try using `numpy.any` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy.any`, as suggested by @DavidG worked to solve my problem.